# "I" and "(","K" keys on the keyboard respond only after pressing them several times

Tags: macos, keyboard

"I" and "(", "K" keys on my Bluetooth keyboard don't work very well sometimes I need to press them several times before the input is print. My battery is at 100% and I think is a problem related to a software I've installed (Anaconda a Python distribution with Spyder) even if this problem occur in general use. I've tried to use **Safe Mode** but it continue to happen... How can I fix it?

**note that in my keyboard I have to hold on shift to use one of these keys**

Comment: Why do you think it is the fault of software, and not of the keyboard?

Comment: Try another keyboard, that will tell you immediately whether the current one is simply damaged.

Comment: @TomG Unfortunatly I have non USB keyboard I've tried to use the Keyboard with my tablet and It works perfectly.

Comment: @GEdgar now I've try with the tablet but I thought if the button doesn't work why it works without shift pressed and if shift doesn't work why it works with the other keys...

Comment: @GEdgar now doesn't work with the tablet , you was right are there any way to reset the keyboard?